# What to call the following variant of tame ramification

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, nt.number-theory, ramification

Suppose that $R \subseteq S$ is a generically separable extension of 1-dimensional normal domains (you can assume that $R$ is local if you'd like) of equal-characteristic $p > 0$ (for simplicity, as you'll see, it's not really needed).

Suppose that for each point $x \in \text{Spec} R$, there exists a point $y \in \text{Spec} S$ such that $R_x \subseteq S_y$ has tame ramification (ie, the residue field extension is separable and if we write, $r = us^n$ where $r$ and $s$ are uniformizers for $R_x$ and $S_y$ respectively, then $p \not | n$).

**Question:**  Does this condition have a name?  (ie, weakly tame, domesticated :-), etc)

I think this condition is also the same as requiring that the trace map $\text{Tr}: S \to R$ is surjective.  In the case that $R \subseteq S$ is generically Galois, Kerz and Schmidt have called this surjective trace condition *cohomologically tamely ramified*.  Has anyone else seen a name for this surjective trace condition especially in the non-1-dimensional case?

Comment: +1 for domesticated :-) If there is no standard terminology, then you have a good candidate there.

Comment: Not that I have any idea if this has a name or that I should mingle in the naming business, but I would say that *domesticated* sounds "tamer" to me, than *tame*. In other words, I could easily imagine something that's tame, yet not domesticated, but less so for something that's domesticated but not tame. At the same time, I don't know what would be a good word that's sort of tame, but a bit less so. Maybe *docile*? Then again, one should always keep in mind Miles Reid's comment about non-native speakers' ideas about naming things....



Comment: Sandor, I agree, domesticated sounds tamer than tame.  I'm still hoping this has been named something else.  Actually, I think the suggestion for domesticated was Aaron Bertram's when I asked some people at tea yesterday if they knew if this had a name..